# Getting TypeError in Build Phase of my React project on windows but nothing on mac or another windows PC

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

check that [error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWY1l.png). I am trying to build my project but it fails because of `uncaughtException TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length').` However, it successfully take build in github workflow when I open a Pull Request. I have tried on my mac, it builds well but I couldn't understand why on my window, it is not building. When I clone the project from stract, it builds successfully again. Any idea about that?

I have deleted node_modules and try installing them from stracth but it didn't work